# I got this error when I running the code of Linear Regression ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Country Manager'

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, valueerror, train-test-split

```
LR.fit(X_train,y_train)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-2654021ed0e5> in <module>()
----> 1 LR.fit(X_train,y_train)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    744                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    745                 else:
--> 746                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    747             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    748                 raise ValueError(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Country Manager'
```

Comment: error message is clear , plus you have not provided any code data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.